# Unintended interaction between tkinter checkbuttons

Tags: variables, tkinter, python-3.8

I am writing a small program that:

- takes an excel file
- read some potential file names from that excel file
- searches for files where the potential file name is part of that name

My problem is: I have two columns with checkbuttons. But for some reasen the checkbuttons in column1 (cb) is bound to the checkbuttons in column2 (cb2). So when pressing a checkbutton in either column1 or column2, the corresponding checkbutton in the other column is checked or unchecked.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

class FileMover:
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = tk.Tk()
        self.master.title('File Mover')
        self.master.geometry('700x700')
        self.master.resizable(0,0)

        self.source_folder_path = ''
        self.destination_folder_path = ''

        self.part_dict = {}

        self.mainframe = tk.Frame(self.master, height=700, width=700, highlightbackground='red', highlightthickness=0)
        self.mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.mainframe.grid_propagate(False)

        self.top_frame = tk.Frame(self.mainframe, height=84, width=700, highlightbackground='blue', highlightthickness=3)
        self.top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.top_frame.grid_propagate(False)
        
        self.center_frame = tk.Frame(self.mainframe, height=700-2*80-2*3, width=700, highlightbackground='red', highlightthickness=0)
        self.center_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.center_frame.grid_propagate(False)

        self.botton_frame = tk.Frame(self.mainframe, height=80, width=700, highlightbackground='red', highlightthickness=3)
        self.botton_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='s')
        self.botton_frame.grid_propagate(False)

        self.left_frame = tk.Frame(self.center_frame, height=700-2*80, width=350, highlightbackground='blue', highlightthickness=3)
        self.left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.left_frame.grid_propagate(False)

        self.right_frame = tk.Frame(self.center_frame, height=700-2*80, width=350, highlightbackground='green', highlightthickness=3)
        self.right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.right_frame.grid_propagate(False)


        self.b_get_part_list = tk.Button(self.top_frame, text='Select Part List', width=20, command=self.get_file_names).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.b_get_source_folder = tk.Button(self.top_frame, text='Select Source Folder', width=20, command=self.get_source_folder).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.b_get_destination_folder = tk.Button(self.top_frame, text='Select Destination Folder', width=20, command=self.get_destination_folder).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')

        self.left_scroller = tk.Scrollbar(self.left_frame)
        self.left_scroller.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

        self.left_text =tk.Text(self.left_frame, width=40, height=33)
        self.left_text.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.left_text.config(yscrollcommand=self.left_scroller.set)
        self.left_scroller.config(command=self.left_text.yview)

        self.right_scroller = tk.Scrollbar(self.right_frame)
        self.right_scroller.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

        self.right_text = tk.Text(self.right_frame, width=40, height=33)
        self.right_text.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.right_text.config(yscrollcommand=self.right_scroller.set)
        self.right_scroller.config(command=self.right_text.yview)

    def get_file_names(self):
        excel_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select Part List', filetypes=[('Excel Files', '*.xlsx')])
        l1 = tk.Label(self.top_frame, text=f'{excel_file_path}')
        l1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w')
        df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)
        col_A = 'Unnamed: 0'
        col_B = 'Unnamed: 1'
        index_start = 16
        index_end = len(df[col_A])
        for index in range(index_start, index_end, 1):
            if (df.iloc[index][col_A] and df.iloc[index][col_B]) not in self.part_dict:
                if not np.isnan(df.iloc[index][col_A]):
                    self.part_dict[str(df.iloc[index][col_A])] = {}
                    self.part_dict[str(df.iloc[index][col_A])]['variable_cb'] = tk.IntVar()
                else:
                    self.part_dict[str(df.iloc[index][col_B])] = {}
                    self.part_dict[str(df.iloc[index][col_B])]['variable_cb'] = tk.IntVar() 
        self.cb_packer()

    def cb_packer(self):
        for index, key in enumerate(self.part_dict):
            cb = tk.Checkbutton(self.left_frame, text=key, bg='white', command=lambda i=index: self.cb_changer(list(self.part_dict)[i]))
            self.left_text.window_create('end', window=cb)
            self.left_text.insert('end', '\n')
    
    def cb_changer(self, name):
        if self.part_dict[name]['variable_cb'].get() != 1:
            self.part_dict[name]['variable_cb'].set(1)
            print(self.part_dict[name]['variable_cb'].get())
        else:
            self.part_dict[name]['variable_cb'].set(0)
            print(self.part_dict[name]['variable_cb'].get())

    def cb2_packer(self):
        for index, key in enumerate(self.part_dict):
            try:
                cb2 = tk.Checkbutton(self.right_frame, text=self.part_dict[key]['file'], bg='white', command=lambda i=index: self.cb2_changer(list(self.part_dict)[i]))
                self.right_text.window_create('end', window=cb2)
                self.right_text.insert('end', '\n')
            except:
                pass

    def cb2_changer(self, name):
        if self.part_dict[name]['variable_cb2'].get() != 1:
            self.part_dict[name]['variable_cb2'].set(1)
            print(self.part_dict[name]['variable_cb2'].get())
        else:
            self.part_dict[name]['variable_cb2'].set(0)
            print(self.part_dict[name]['variable_cb2'].get())
                    
    def get_source_folder(self):
        self.source_folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory(title='Select Source Folder')
        l2 = tk.Label(self.top_frame, text=f'{self.source_folder_path}')
        l2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')
        self.file_crawler()
        self.cb2_packer()

    def file_crawler(self):
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(self.source_folder_path):
            for file in files:
                for key in self.part_dict:
                    if key in file:
                        try:
                            self.part_dict[key]['file']
                        except:
                            if file.endswith('pdf') or file.endswith('PDF') or file.endswith('dxf') or file.endswith('DXF') or file.endswith('stp') or file.endswith('STP') or file.endswith('step') or file.endswith('STEP'):
                                self.part_dict[key]['path'] = path
                                self.part_dict[key]['file'] = file
                                self.part_dict[key]['variable_cb2'] = tk.IntVar()

    def get_destination_folder(self):
        pass


gui = FileMover()
gui.master.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use `.csv` files: they can be read easier because they are raw text. Furthermore you can export an excel file into `.csv`.

Comment: I am not the one producing the the xlsx file. My problem is that when checking or unchecking a checkbutton the checkbutton in the other column is also checked or unchecked.

Comment: Ok, I know, I just wanted to tell you about this option. This way you can avoid errors coming from the way you use the modules used to read the file.

Comment: You've posted far too much code. Can you please trim this down to a [mcve]?

Comment: I am not 100% sure which parts of my code is causing the error. My bet would be, that it is somewhere in one of the following functions: cb_packer, cb2_packer, cb_changer or cb2_changer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your code this part may behave weird:

```
    col_A = 'Unnamed: 0'
    col_B = 'Unnamed: 1'
    index_start = 16
    index_end = len(df[col_A])
    for index in range(index_start, index_end, 1):
        if (df.iloc[index][col_A] and df.iloc[index][col_B]) not in self.part_dict:
            if not np.isnan(df.iloc[index][col_A]):
                self.part_dict[str(df.iloc[index][col_A])] = {}
                self.part_dict[str(df.iloc[index][col_A])]['variable_cb'] = tk.IntVar()
            else:
                self.part_dict[str(df.iloc[index][col_B])] = {}
                self.part_dict[str(df.iloc[index][col_B])]['variable_cb'] = tk.IntVar() 
    self.cb_packer()
```

The keys in the dictionary are `str(df.iloc[index][col_B])`, being the variables from the sheet. These may be not unique.